# How to unstack a dataframe without creating nan?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, nan

I'm starting with a dataframe as below (df2):

| - | Day | Sorbent | Gabapentin 1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | AX | 0.0 |
| 1 | 1 | AX | 0.0 |
| 2 | 1 | AX | 0.0 |
| 3 | 1 | ABN | 0.0 |
| 4 | 1 | ABN | 0.0 |
| .. | ... | ... | ... |
| 84 | 30 | Dex | 4.4 |

I want to end up with a data frame as below:

|  | Day | ABN | AX | Dex | ENV | WCX |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| 3 | 4 | 0.0 | 0.3 | 0.1 | 0.0 | 0.1 |
| 4 | 4 | 0.0 | 0.3 | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.2 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | .. |  |
| 30 | 30 | 0.0 | 3.3 | 4.4 | 8.5 | 10.1 |

So I have tried a variety of input and the closest I can get is:

```
df3 = df2.set_index(['Day', 'Sorbent'], append = True)
print(df3.unstack(level = -1))
```

Which gives:

```
    Gabapentin 1
```

| Sorbent | ABN | AX | Dex | ENV | WCX |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | Day |  |  |  |  |
| 0 | 1 | NaN | 0.0 | NaN | NaN |
| 1 | 1 | NaN | 0.0 | NaN | NaN |
| 2 | 1 | NaN | 0.0 | NaN | NaN |
| 3 | 1 | 0.0 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 4 | 1 | 0.0 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| ... |  | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 84 | 30 | NaN | NaN | 0.0 | NaN |
| 85 | 30 | NaN | NaN | 0.0 | NaN |
| 86 | 30 | NaN | NaN | NaN | 0.0 |
| 87 | 30 | NaN | NaN | NaN | 0.0 |
| 88 | 30 | NaN | NaN | NaN | 0.0 |

I've tried pivots etc. but I don't want the data averaged out.

If anyone has any ideas I'm sure I'm just missing something really silly but I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Apologies, I did apply formatting but I'm not sure why it isn't posting with the formatting

Comment: Looks to be due to a missing empty line before the table (although it looked correct in the edit preview). I fixed it but the last table looks incorrect, you can [edit] the question to fix it.